# Adjunctions with respect to profunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, 2-categories, profunctors

Let $P : W° \times Y \to \mathbf{Set}$ and $Q : X° \times V \to \mathbf{Set}$ be [profunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor), and let $L : X \to W$ and $R : Y \to V$ be functors. Suppose that $$P(Lx, y) \cong Q(x, Ry)$$ natural in $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$ [1]. Is there a name for such a relationship, and is it subsumed by some other concept, e.g. adjunctions in $\mathbf{Prof}$? In particular, it would be useful to prove statements about these "adjunctions with respect to profunctors", for instance giving characterisations of (co)reflective adjunctions with respect to profunctors, using known statements about adjunctions more generally.

[1] Such situations were actually studied in the original paper on adjoint functors, Kan's *Adjoint functors*, under the term "rel. adjointness". However, Kan did not have the richness of abstraction that we have today, so his treatment of them is quite concrete. The only examples given are essentially representable, in that they're induced by [closed structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category).

Comment: I have studied for a little while the case $P=Q$ (because the step I made was generalising $\hom\mapsto P$); if I'm correct, every adjunction $F \dashv G$ for which $F \dashv_P G$ -meaning that $P(F-,-)\cong P(-,G-)$- induces a "hom-relative" adjunction from the category of elements/collage of $P$ to itself; probably for generic $P,Q$ you get an adjunction between to different collages?

Comment: Of course, this can also be written as just a commutative square in Prof, where one of the profunctors is representable and one other is corepresentable.

Comment: @MikeShulman: indeed. The question then becomes, I suppose, "Can properties of such diagrams be deduced from existing theory (e.g. the theory of adjunctions in a 2-category), without having to reprove various results about adjunctions at this greater level of generality?".

Comment: Well, it probably depends on what sort of properties you want to prove.  But I would expect that most things you might want to prove about such a thing, and that are actually true, would follow from this expression and the fact that representable (resp. corepresentable) profunctors are left (resp. right) adjoints in Prof.

Comment: You might need to move to the proarrow equipment $\rm Cat \hookrightarrow Prof$, but it seems unlikely in this case since there are no other functors in sight.

Comment: I've discovered the same question was [asked here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44687/adjunction-up-to-distributor/44721).

Comment: Personally, I think this question could have benefitted from linking to the definition of "profunctor" and a bit more motivation. For example, it would have been nice to mention if there was a concrete application of this notion in Kan's paper. Just my two cents.

Comment: @DavidWhite: thanks for the suggestion. I've added a couple of links. My motivation for this question was primarily abstract: it seems a natural concept to consider (and indeed, Kan did), and I was wondering if it had been studied anywhere. Kan does not give any convincing examples.

Answer (score 2):

I remember I tried to work with this definition for a while when I still believed in the notion of relative category. Under some coherence assumptions, your notion is related to the classical notion of adjunction. Follow me in the presentation below.

**Def.** A virtual relative category is a couple $(\mathsf{C}, \rho)$ where $\mathsf{C}$ is a category and $\rho: \mathsf{C}(-,-) \Rightarrow \mathsf{P}(-,-) $ is an epimorphism in $\mathsf{Psh}(\mathsf{C}^\circ \times \mathsf{C}).$

In my original definition $\mathsf{P}$ was assumed to be small, and the whole definition had the advantage that I could use Kan extensions freely, because size issues where taken care of by this smallness assumption.

**Rem.** Every virtual relative category has an homotopy category, $\mathsf{Ho}_\rho(\mathsf{C})$ having the same objects of $C$ and where $\mathsf{Ho}_\rho(\mathsf{C})(a,b) = \mathsf{P
}(a,b)$. Moreover, $\rho$ indudes a quotient functor $C \to \mathsf{Ho}_\rho(\mathsf{C})$.

This Rem. shows the perks of this notion. For a honest relative category $(\mathsf{C},\mathcal{W})$ one cannot guarantee for the existence of an homotopy category. Of course, smallness is not used at this point, but one starts to see that the whole structure is tamer than the usual notion.

**Def.** An homotopical functor $f$ between virtual relative categories is a functor $f: \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$ such that there exists a (necessary unique)  $\bar{f}: \mathsf{P}_\mathsf{C}(-,-) \Rightarrow \mathsf{P}_\mathsf{D}(-,-)$ making the obvious diagram involving $\rho$ commutative.

**Def.** A Quillen adjunction between virtual homotopy categories is a couple of homotopical functors (in opposite directions) such that $\mathsf{P}_\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{L}c,d) \cong \mathsf{P}_\mathsf{D}(c, \mathsf{R}d)$.

**Prop**. A Quillen adjunction between virtual relative categories induces an adjunction between their homotopy categories.

**Rem**. The proposition above shows that, to the price of passing to the homotopy category, this kind of $\mathsf{P}$-relative adjunctions are actually subsumed by honest adjunctions. Moreover, this idea (which has a very homotpical flavour) can be stretched to the case in which $\mathsf{P}$ is just an endoprofunctor (without $\rho$ you lose the quotient functor). Otherwise, I do not see how to define Homotopy categories.

Comment: How do you ensure that $\mathsf{Ho}_\rho(\mathsf{C})$ is a category? Certainly it will be if $\mathsf P$ is a monad in $\mathsf{Prof}$: is it related to this fact?

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, that was an assumption. I just forgot about it.